# How to map a function across multiple ragged lists

Tags: list-manipulation

## Preliminaries

I have lists that are **lists of lists** (i.e., each list contains one or more sublists and are **ragged** (i.e., each sublist can have a different length, though all have a length of 1 or greater).  However, each list is *similarly ragged* -- each list has the same number of sublists, and corresponding sublists have the same length.

As an example, consider the lists `listA`, `listB`, and `listC`:

```
listA = {{A1x}, {A2x, A2y, A2z}, {A3x, A3y}, {A4x, A4y, A4z, A4a}};
listB = {{B1x}, {B2x, B2y, B2z}, {B3x, B3y}, {B4x, B4y, B4z, B4a}};
listC = {{C1x}, {C2x, C2y, C2z}, {C3x, C3y}, {C4x, C4y, C4z, C4a}};
```

## Objective

I wish to write a function `myFunction` that maps a function `func` across corresponding elements of two or more lists.  `myFunction` would have the form

> **myFunction[func, lists__]**

I wish to define `myFunction` such that the function call

```
myFunction[f, listA, listB] (* function call 1 *)
```

returns this output:

> ```
> (* function call 1 desired output *)
> {
>  {f[{A1x, B1x}]},
>  {f[{A2x, B2x}], f[{A2y, B2y}], f[{A2z, B2z}]},
>  {f[{A3x, B3x}], f[{A3y, B3y}]},
>  {f[{A4x, B4x}], f[{A4y, B4y}], f[{A4z, B4z}], f[{A4a, B4a}]}
> }
> ```

while the function call

```
myFunction[f, listA, listB, listC] (* function call 2 *)
```

returns this output:

> ```
> (* function call 2 desired output *)
> {
>  {f[{A1x, B1x, C1x}]},
>  {f[{A2x, B2x, C2x}], f[{A2y, B2y, C2y}], f[{A2z, B2z, C2z}]},
>  {f[{A3x, B3x, C3x}], f[{A3y, B3y, C3y}]},
>  {f[{A4x, B4x, C4x}], f[{A4y, B4y, C4y}], f[{A4z, B4z, C4z}], f[{A4a, B4a, C4a}]}
> }
> ```

where `f` can be the built-in function [`Mean`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mean.html) to compute a simple average.

Additionally, I would like `myFunction` to be compatible with *Mathematica* 9 and later, so `myFunction` needs to use functions available in *Mathematica* 9 or earlier.

**Could you please help me think through how to accomplish this?** (I am *not* a student and this is *not* a homework assignment.)

## Attempts at reaching the objective

I've started by considering the first function call, `myFunction[f, listA, listB]`, which involves only two lists.  Combining `Map` and `Transpose` gets me seemingly somewhat close to my goal:

```
myFunction[func_, list1_List, list2_List] := Map[func, Transpose[{listA, listB}];

myFunction[f, listA, listB]
```

> ```
> (* output *)
> {
>  f[{{A1x}, {B1x}}], 
>  f[{{A2x, A2y, A2z}, {B2x, B2y, B2z}}], 
>  f[{{A3x, A3y}, {B3x, B3y}}], 
>  f[{{A4x, A4y, A4z, A4a}, {B4x, B4y, B4z, B4a}}]
> }
> ```

... except that I would need `f` to be mapped deeper for sublists with length greater than 1. One (not very elegant) way to do this may be:

```
myFunction[func_, list1_List, list2_List] := Map[
 If[
   Length[#[[1]]] == 1, {func[Flatten[#]]},
   Map[func, Transpose[#]]
   ] &,
 Transpose[{listA, listB}]];

myFunction[f, listA, listB]
```

> ```
> (* output *)
> {
>  {f[{A1x, B1x}]}, 
>  {f[{A2x, B2x}], f[{A2y, B2y}], f[{A2z, B2z}]}, 
>  {f[{A3x, B3x}], f[{A3y, B3y}]}, 
>  {f[{A4x, B4x}], f[{A4y, B4y}], f[{A4z, B4z}], f[{A4a, B4a}]}
> }
> ```

I imagine there's a much more elegant, compact way to do that, but this appears to work. But even if I use this definition, I still need to generalize it to 3 or more input lists.

How do I do that? I think I need to use the [`BlankSequence[]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlankSequence.html) pattern object (two `_` characters) for the lists input:

```
myFunction[func_, lists__] := Map[
  If[
    Length[#[[1]]] == 1, {func[Flatten[#]]},
    Map[func, Transpose[#]]
    ] &,
  Transpose[{lists}]];

myFunction[f, listA, listB, listC]
```

> ```
> (* output *)
> {
>  {f[{A1x,B1x,C1x}]},
>  {f[{A2x,B2x,C2x}],f[{A2y,B2y,C2y}],f[{A2z,B2z,C2z}]},
>  {f[{A3x,B3x,C3x}],f[{A3y,B3y,C3y}]},
>  {f[{A4x,B4x,C4x}],f[{A4y,B4y,C4y}],f[{A4z,B4z,C4z}],f[{A4a,B4a,C4a}]}
> }
> ```

And this is the result I was looking for. **Is there a more compact way to do this?** [`MapThread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html) looks possibly useful, but it's not clear to me how to use for my particular application.

Comment: like that? : `Function[, f[{##}], Listable][listA, listB]`

Comment: @Kuba :  `Function[, f[##] ...` , not `Function[, f[{##}] ...`

Comment: Kuba's solution is probably what you need, except if what you describe here as atoms (`A1X`, `A2X` etc...) are in fact themselves Lists ( {} )

Comment: How about `MapThread[MapThread[f@*List]@*List, {listA, listB, listC}]`?

Comment: @andre314 Thank you, everyone! The atoms I describe are in fact themselves numbers -- integers and reals -- not Lists.

Comment: @andre314 but OP asked for `f[{A1x, B1x}]` not `f[A1x, B1x]` and for the latter case just making `f` `Listable` will do the job.

Answer (score 7):

```
MapThread[f@*List] /@ Transpose[lists]
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm just putting this here to have an actual answer instead of just comments. The key insight here is that the Listable attribute provides this functionality nicely. Here are two possibilities that match your method signature, but there are other options, perhaps nicer for some circumstances, if you relaxed that requirement a bit:

```
(* option 1*)
SetAttributes[myFunction1, Listable];
myFunction1[f_, args__] := f[{args}]

(* option 2*)
myFunction2 = Function[, #1[{##2}], Listable]
```

Answer (score 2):

By using `Thread` we would get:

```
Thread /@ Thread[f[listA, listB]]

(* Out: {{f[A1x, B1x]}, {f[A2x, B2x], f[A2y, B2y], f[A2z, B2z]}, {f[A3x, B3x], f[A3y, B3y]}, {f[A4x, B4x], f[A4y, B4y], f[A4z, B4z], f[A4a, B4a]}} *)
```

For replacing `f[a1,a2]` to `f[{a1, a2}]` we can use:

##### 1. By `Hold`

```
ReleaseHold[Thread /@ Thread[Hold[f@*List][listA, listB]]]

(* Out: {{f[{A1x, B1x}]}, {f[{A2x, B2x}], f[{A2y, B2y}], f[{A2z, B2z}]}, {f[{A3x, B3x}], f[{A3y, B3y}]}, {f[{A4x, B4x}], f[{A4y, B4y}], f[{A4z, B4z}], f[{A4a, B4a}]}} *)
```

##### 2. By `Apply`

```
Apply[f@*List, Thread /@ Thread@{listA, listB}, {2}]

(* Out: {{f[{A1x, B1x}]}, {f[{A2x, B2x}], f[{A2y, B2y}], f[{A2z, B2z}]}, {f[{A3x, B3x}], f[{A3y, B3y}]}, {f[{A4x, B4x}], f[{A4y, B4y}], f[{A4z, B4z}], f[{A4a, B4a}]}} *)
```

The above solutions (especially second) are slightly faster than @Alan, but use more memory!